# Codeigniter - session db or session cookies benchmarking

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

Hello i would like to know if using the codeigniter session with db is slower than using simple cookies session.

Specifically i would like from some of you to specify which is the work flow of the session using db and the workflow of the session using cookies.

Details are important , really thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better security to use DB sessions.
But if you want you may use and normal sessions..

Comment: great now i'm using normal session and the app is just in production server does i need to change somenthing to use db session, somenthing like $this->session->userdata() will be deprecated?